# Solve parametric equation with constraint on the range

Tags: calculus, parametric

I would like to solve the following system:
$$
\begin{cases}
 x =\sin(u)\\ 
 y=\sin(2u)
\end{cases}
$$
with${ \;0\leq u \leq\pi}$ (and not until $2\pi$!). This is illutrated with the following picture:

[image]

When I solve the equation we can obtain:
$$
y^2=4x^2(1-x^2)
$$

However this gives a famous butterfly shape:
[image]

How do I obtain an equation as above without restricting $x$ to be positive?

Comment: Maybe you could try to write $\sin{2u}$ in terms of $\sin{u}$?

Comment: $u=\frac {\pi} 2+\arctan (-\frac y {2x^{2}})$. You get this using the fact that $\sin (2u)=2 \sin (u)\cos (u)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did this and it gave me the solution $y^2=4x^2(1-x^2)$. But I do not know how to obtain an equation describing a single part without having to restrict the range of $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve the system" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is virtually impossible.

You can look for a solution of the form

$$y^2=4x^2(1-x^2)\,\text{sgn}(f(x))$$

where the function $f$ ensures that the product remains negative in the negative $x$, i.e. $$f(x)<0\iff x\in(-1,0).$$

This is obtained with $f(x)=\text{sgn}(x(1+x))$, leading to

$$y^2=|x\,(1+x)|\,x\,(1-x).$$

The RHS has the merit of being defined everywhere and to be continuous. But there is a but: it also cancels at $x=-1$, giving an extra isolated point, and this is irreparable, because this zero is independent of the function $f$.

---

You can also work additively and design a function which is zero in $[0,1]$ and sufficiently negative elsewhere. For instance

$$y^2=4x^2(1-x^2)+1-|x|-|x-1|.$$ The plot shows the RHS (in magenta the original function, in green the negative term, in blue the result).

[image]

If the absolute value function is allowed, then this fulfills the request. But it is so ugly !

---

You can also add a term that restricts the domain to the non-negatives and is neutral in the positives, such as $\sqrt x-\sqrt{|x|}$, but IMO this is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: This does the trick...
$$
y^2=4|x|x(1-x^2)
$$

Comment: It doesn't. For instance $(-1,0)$ does fulfill this implicit equation.

Comment: To the upvoter: before upvoting, check the answers.